# Arithmetic operations in AT&T assembly (adding memory and a register)

Tags: c, assembly, cpu-registers

I am having trouble understanding the behavior of adding two values, one in a register and one in memory.

Assume for memory we have:

```
Address   Value
0x100     0xFF
```

And assume for registers, we have:

```
 Register    Value
 %eax        0x100
 %ecx        0x1
```

Now my undrestanding is that when you use (%eax) as an operand, what you're doing is referencing the memory at that address, i.e., you'll get the value 0xFF, i.e

```
(%eax) = 0xFF
```

But when (%eax) is the destination of an addition or subtraction, the reference (%eax) gives us back the address in memory instead of referencing the memory (similar to lea behavior), i.e.,

```
addl %ecx, (%eax)
```

writes 0x1 + 0xFF to 0x100. What is confusing me is that when we read the value to perform the addition (%eax) gives us back 0xFF, but when we use (%eax) as the destiation of addition, we write to 0x100.

Can someone explain this please?

Comment: I think your disconnect is when using `add` you are not writing anywhere. `add` operates on `registers` taking the value of the `src` and adding it to the `target` **register**. Your confusion comes from the fact that `0xFF + 0x1 = 0x100`. You have a **memory address** of `0x100` and you have a **result of addition** equal to `0x100`, but the two are not related as far as any **write** is concerned. I hope that is clearer than mud. In assembly, you load values into registers and operate on them with `add`. You write with `movs` and `stos` and move values with `mov`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when we read the value to perform the addition `(%eax)` gives us back 0xFF, but when we use `(%eax)` as the destiation of addition, we write to 0x100.
>   Can someone explain this please?

In both cases, using `(%eax)` as an operand means referencing memory at the address contained in `%eax`. The address in your example is 0x100, and the doubleword at that address contains the value 0xFF.

If you do a read - e.g. `movl (%eax),%ecx` - you simply grab the value at 0x100, so you get `0xFF`.

If you do `addl %ecx,(%eax)` you first read from memory address 0x100 (i.e. the value 0xFF), add the value of `%ecx` (1) to it to get the value 0x100, and then write the result back to the same address that you read it from (0x100). Note that the value of `%eax` never changes during this operation; it's just the value *pointed to* by `%eax` that changes.

Comment: I wonder who set that problem up for him. That was sure a pernicious choice of address.

Comment: makes absolute sense now, basically when i read it, I get the contents, when I write it, I replace the contents. as far as the address is concerned, it's pointing to the same location, only the contents have changed. 

Thanks both.